# How to convert a nested list into a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-lists

I would like to take a nested list such as:

```
list = [[Name, Height, Weight],[Dan, 175, 75],[Mark, 165, 64], [Sam, 183, 83]]
```

and convert it into a dictionary like:

```
dict = {Name: [Dan,Mark, Sam], Height: [175, 165, 183], Weight: [75, 64, 83]}
```

my current code is unfortunately not really giving me the dictionary format I'm looking for.

```py
i = 1
z = 0
for items in list[0]:
    dict[items] = [list[i][z]]
    i += 1
z += 1
```

can someone please assist me and find where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Please don't use builtin names for variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Separate the keys and the rest first, then construct the dictionary with `zip`:

```
keys, *rest = list_of_lists

out = dict(zip(keys, zip(*rest)))
```

where `list_of_lists` is what you called `list` (but please refrain from that as it shadows the builtin `list`). First `*` is slurping all the lists starting from second one. The second `*` in `zip` kind of transposes the lists to reorder them

to get

```
>>> out

{"Name": ("Dan", "Mark", "Sam"),
 "Height": (175, 165, 183),
 "Weight": (75, 64, 83)}
```

---

this gives tuples in the values but to get lists, you can `map`:

```
out = dict(zip(keys, map(list, zip(*rest))))
```

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation!

Answer (score 2):

@Mustafa's answer is the most concise but if you are a beginner you might find it easier to break it down into steps.

```
data =[
    ['Name', 'Height', 'Weight'], 
    ['Dan', 175, 75], ['Mark', 165, 64], ['Sam', 183, 83]
]
keys = data[0]
values = [list(items) for items in zip(*data[1:])]
results = dict(zip(keys, values))
```

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to stackoverflow :)

We seldom use `i++` `i+=1` for loop count or step in python if we can easily use `for i in ...` even if we don't know how many list in it.

your original data is a list of list. first list is the key of dictionary, other list is each records.

we often use `zip(*your_list)` when your data (list in list) is equal length. `zip` function will help you rearrange `your_list`. the `*` in front of `your_list` means put each record in `your_list` to zip function's argument one by one
then put it in a for loop, like `for rec in zip(list):`.

so, you can write your code like:

```
your_dict = {}
for rec in zip(yout_list):
    k = rec[0] #dict key
    v = list(rec[1:]) #dict value, convert to list if needed
    your_dict[k] = v # set key and value
```

e.g.

[image]

that's it!

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation, I’m new to python and programming in general so I’ll definitely take everything on board!